# Firebase: Iterate over map

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got a collection called "inventar" which contains a doc with an auto generated value which contains a single map I want to iterate about.

Note that the keys are going to vary, because the user is going to specify it.

How can I iterate over this map so that I can output the key and value in my table cells listed below?

[image]

```
new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("inventar")
                    .where("verfallsdatum")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Something went wrong');
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text("Loading");
                  }

                  return new Table(
                    children: [
                      new TableRow(children: [
                        new TableCell(child: new Text("Produkt")),
                        new TableCell(child: new Text("Verfallsdatum")),
                      ]),

                      // how to iterate here?

                        new TableRow(
                          children: [
                            new TableCell(
                              child: new Text("key"),
                            ),
                            new TableCell(
                              child: new Text("value"),
                            ),
                          ]
                        )
                    ]);
                },
              )
```

Edit:
I am trying to get this data out of my database since alomost one month! Which major mistake or misunderstanding do I have, that I am unable to query single document which contains a map and output it as table? Is this task so awefuly rough to perform or am I just dumb? :D

Here is the recent attampt I did, but it says there is no method "forEach" for the type "DocumentSnapshot" even though I think I say this attampt in pretty much every tutorial. But mine aint work!

```
    var products = await db.collection("inventar").doc("vqQXArtqnFyAlkPC1PHr").get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("inventar")
          .where("verfallsdatum")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((documentSnapshot) {
            var _data = documentSnapshot.data();

            return _data.map((key, value) {
              return new Table(children: [
                new TableRow(children: [
                  new TableCell(child: new Text("Produkt")),
                  new TableCell(child: new Text("Verfallsdatum")),
                ]),

                // how to iterate here?

                new TableRow(children: [
                  new TableCell(
                    child: new Text(key),
                  ),
                  new TableCell(
                    child: new Text(value),
                  ),
                ])
              ]);
            }).toList();
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I use your code, I get an error message "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'".

Besides from that, I think, your code would produce a new table for every entry in the map, which unfortunaly is not what I want.

Comment: this api `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("inventar").where("verfallsdatum").snapshots()` will return you multiple documents from the collection which is instance of `QuerySnapshot`, and it should have `.docs` getter which will return `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>` if this is not a case for you, can you post what version of cloud_firestore you are using mine is `cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0`

Comment: oh, my bad it should be `snapshot.data.docs.map` not `snapshot.docs.map` I just made correction

Comment: Hi Ara, I just tried out your approach and get several errors. First, the children property of the ListView-Widget says "The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'" and "The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'." Second, the line which returns the table says "The return type 'Table' isn't a 'MapEntry<_, _>', as required by the closure's context". Don't think we are on the right path here.